# eps graphic doesn't show up in dvi output

Tags: graphics, eps, dvi

I tried to use `\munepsfig` in my document, no error, no warning.

Just my image doesn't show, what could be actually wrong? Which file should I check to know the problem?

Anyway, I use a template given by someone else, it worked perfectly, this happened when I change the image.

Edit: just found out that `\munepsfig{}` is actually a new command, but no other than `\begin{figure}\includegraphics{}\end{figure}`, but it still didn't show (when I just use the normal figure), is there something wrong here?

The example I had:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{memoir} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{testing} 

\begin{figure}[h] 
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{logo2.eps} 
  \caption{testing} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Somebody thinks that `\includegraphics` has to go inside a `figure` environment: it's not true. Your problem might be in incompatible formats for the figure: latex accepts only eps, while pdflatex doesn't (and accepts png, jpg and pdf).

Comment: @zfm: We need a minimal example, including at least a pointer to the graphics file in question.

Comment: it's very simple example I had. `begin{figure}\includegraphics{file.eps}\caption{File}\end{figure}`. The caption was there, the area was there, but the image wasn't, it's just a blank, white screen on the area that should be filled with the image

Comment: @Joseph: http://www.4shared.com/file/ot8m4BB1/logo.html
http://www.4shared.com/file/x-a5dDgi/enrollment.html (I dont know if there's a possibility to put an `.eps` file here)

Comment: @zfm --- I can't reproduce your problem. As Joseph says, we need a minimal example.

Comment: @Ian: what do you mean with "minimal example"?

Comment: @zfm --- it is explained in [this question on the meta site](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @Ian: okay, I will produce it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Joseph @Ian: I have edited the question, including the example I had.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using plain old LaTeX to produce a dvi file, and then converting that dvi file to either postscript or pdf?  As @egreg points out, pdflatex won't accept an .eps file, only plain old LaTeX will.  Also: After you run LaTeX to produce the dvi file, there's a chance you're using a dvi viewer that doesn't display .eps files; be sure to convert the .dvi to .ps or .pdf and look at that.

Comment: @Phil: yep, I used dvi viewer, and I didn't manage to convert it to .pdf, however, even in dvi viewer, it didn't show anything. So what is the best image filetype that can be seen by both dvi viewer and pdf viewer

Comment: @zfm: I think you misunderstood my suggestion.  I don't know what dvi viewer you're using, so I suggesting converting the dvi to either ps (using dvips) or to pdf (using dvipdf) and then looking at either the ps or the pdf.  (This may not help at all, but it's a thought.)

Comment: @zfm --- your example says `\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{logo2.eps}`, but the link leads to a file called `logo.eps`. Incorrect filenames can cause the problem you describe if TeX is running in nonstop mode.

Comment: @Ian: sorry, I just rename the file, in any case, I got no error on compiling this (I know this for sure since if I tried something like `include...{abcde.eps}` I will get the error). So no problem for this.

Comment: @Phil: yes, that's my stupidity, when I try to convert it to ps, it shows what I need. So case closed, I'm stupid :D

Comment: @Ian: Please turn your last comment plus zfm's reply into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep --- @Phil Hirschhorn correctly diagnosed the problem. He should take the credit for answering.

Comment: @Phil: Please turn your commments into an answer -- you'll get at least one upvote. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be that your graphic was correctly included, but that your dvi viewer isn't showing you the eps file.  (`\includegraphics` inserts the eps file using a `\special`, and not all dvi viewers know how to handle all specials.)  If you convert your dvi file to a ps file (using dvips) or to a pdf file (using dvipdf), you may well find that your graphic displays correctly.